# How to define specify parameter functions of a Sturm-Liouville operator & plot its effect on specific functions?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, operators

I have a Sturm-Liouville operator:

$$\mathcal{Ly(x)}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(p(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}y(x)\right)-q(x)y(x)$$

but I do not yet know the parameter functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, nor the arbitrary function $y(x)$. I define the operator in Mathematica:

```
sl[x_]:=-D[p[x]*D[y[x],x],x]-q[x]*y[x]
```

What if now I want to specify what $p$, $q$ and $y$ should be? Let's say $p(x)=1$, $q(x)=1$ and $y(x)=\sin(x)$. I do:

```
res[x_]:=sl[x]/.{p[x]->1,q[x]->0}/.{y[x]->Sin[x]}
```

To check if this is correct and I can plot `res`, I do:

```
Plot[res[x],{x,0,Pi}]
```

I am getting an empty plot:

[image]

but I expected a $-\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}^2x}\left(\sin(x)\right)=\sin(x)$ plot.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Seemingly reasonable another failed attempts:

1)

```
sl[p_, q_, y_,x_]:=-D[p[x]*D[y[x],x],x]-q[x]*y[x]
res[x_]:=sl[p[x], q[x], y[x], x]/.{p[x]->1,q[x]->0}/.{y[x]->Sin[x]}
```

2. 

Based on the Currying part of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8868/76252):

```
sl[x_][p_,q_]:=-D[p[x]*D[y[x],x],x]-q[x]*y[x]
p[x_]:=1
q[x_]:=0
res[x_]:=sl[x][p, q]
```

3. 

Based on comments:

```
sl[x_]:=((-D[p[x]*D[y[x],x],x]-q[x]*y[x])/.{p[x]->1,q[x]->0})
res[x_]:=sl/.{y[x]->Sin[x]}
```

4. 

Specifying `y` as well in the first line:

```
sl[x_]:=((-D[p[x]*D[y[x],x],x]-q[x]*y[x])/.{p[x]->1,q[x]->0,y[x]->Sin[x]})
```

when plotting it (`Plot[sl[x],{x,0,Pi}]`), I still get errors and no plot.

Comment: What do you get if you just execute `res[x]` for an unspecified `x`? Does the result help you explain the behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I get just `-p'[x]y'[x]-y''[x]`, which suggests I think that I couldn't pass the value for `p` properly for some reason, otherwise it would not be shown as `p`.

Comment: I tried writing `res:= ...` according to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262184/76252). Instead of `VariationalD[(a[x] - s[x])^2, s[x], x]`, I have `sl[x]`. Maybe the problem is that the `p` and `q` dependence is not explicitly statet in my `res` definition, trying to fix that...

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that in your `res` definition `sl[x]` is evaluated before the substitution with `/.` happens, both when `x` is a number and when it is a symbol. In my opinion it is `sl` that should take `p` and `q` as input functions, perhaps as pure `Function`s?

Comment: Thanks you! I added my latest attempts to the question (number 3 is based on these comments), I haven't found a solution yet but keep working on it...

Comment: attempt 4 also added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight replacing the way you have done does not honor derivatives.  You can do it this way:

```
sl[x_] = -D[p[x]*D[y[x], x], x] - q[x]*y[x]

res[x_] = sl[x] /. {p -> (1 &), q[x] -> 0} /. {y -> (Sin[#] &)}
(* Sin[x] *)
```

And you will get the plot you expect.

If you don't want to use pure functions you can do it this way:

```
sl[x] /. {p -> Function[{x}, 1], q -> Function[{x}, 0], 
  y -> Function[{x}, Sin[x]]}
(* Sin[x] *)
```

It is not necessary to make `q` a function in this case because `sl` contains no derivatives of `q`.  But maybe you don't know that up front, so it's OK to do so.  In any case if you want Mathematica to replace the function as well as its derivatives, you need to tell Mathematica it's dealing with a function.  Of course you can always specify `p[x]`, `p'[x]`, etc. separately.

Comment: Thank you. I indeed get the plot. Would you be able to add some explanation or direct me in the right direction to understand why using `p -> (1 &)` works, but `p[x]->1` does not?

Comment: Because `p[x]->1` will properly replace `p[x]` in `sl[x]`, but it will not replace `p'[x]`.

Comment: You don't have that problem with `q[x]` because there are no derivatives of `q[x]` in `sl[x]`.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sl[p_, q_, y_, xv_, var_ : x] := 
  (-D[p*D[y, var], var] - q*y) /. var -> xv

p[x_] = 1;
q[x] = 0;
y[x] = Sin[x];
res[xv_] := sl[p[x], q[x], y[x], xv]

Plot[Evaluate@res[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Another example,

```
p[x_] = x^2;
q[x] = Sqrt[x];
y[x] = x*Sin[x];
res[xv_] := sl[p[x], q[x], y[x], xv]
```

Note the equivalent use of the option `Evaluated` rather than `Evaluate`

```
Plot[res[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I indeed get the plots. Here: `sl[p_, q_, y_, xv_, var_ : x] := 
  (-D[p*D[y, var], var] - q*y) /. var -> xv` what's happening is that we define the right hand side of the formula using `var`, and then we set `var` to `xv` by  `/. var -> xv`, is that correct? Probably `var_ : x` is also a key element on the left hand side. If you could add some explanation to this or direct me to the right direction researching this, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: `var_ : x` is used to indicate that `var` is an optional argument with a default value of `x`. This facilitates handling functions of another variable such as `z`. The `var -> xv` insures that the derivatives are taken prior to a numeric value being assigned to the variable.